# erf() and IntervalRootFinding

Tags: julia

I realize this is a pretty niche problem, but I figure it's worth asking anyway.

I'm working on a program that does root-finding, and the function that it's trying to find a root for involves computing Fresnel integrals, which are implemented using `erf()`. I thought I'd try using the `IntervalRootFinding` package, but haven't gotten very far with it. I get a `MethodError` exception, which looks like:

```
MethodError: no method matching _erf(::Complex{IntervalArithmetic.Interval{Float64}})
```

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`IntervalArithmatic` requires that your functions know how to work with intervals. Since `erf` is monotonic, you could define your own implementation

```
using IntervalArithmatic
erf(x::Interval{T}) where T = Interval(prevfloat(erf(x.lo)), nextfloat(erf(x.hi)))
```

Comment: This is interesting, but erf() takes a complex argument and returns a complex value, and my use of it is definitely using both the real and imaginary parts of the return value.

Comment: then it will be a little more complicated to get a good `erf` implementation that works for `Interval` but it's still possible. Where is `erf` defined?

Comment: It's defined in SpecialFunctions.

Comment: Hmm - I see there's the concept of an IntervalBox defined in IntervalArithmetic. That could be useful.

Comment: Hi @user888379. Have you figured this out since then? If so, could you add it as an answer here?

Comment: @SundarR Afraid I haven't. The project this is for has been put on the back burner, and I've moved on to other tasks.